# React-Native OnPress function giving error

Tags: android, react-native

I have one js file having code -

```
var List = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    hprops: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  renderRow: function(rowData) {
    return <HelloView {...rowData} style={styles.row} />
  },

  render: function() {
    var dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(data);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.headline}>Hello</Text>
        <Button
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.notifyPresence(dataSource)}>
          Notify presence!
        </Button>
        <ListView
          dataSource={dataSource}
          renderRow={this.render.bind(this)}
          enableEmptySections
        />
      </View>
    );
  },
});
```

And another index.android.js in which this notifyPresense function is declared:

```
_notifyPresence(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
```

On button press i am getting error as undefined function.
Can anyone suggest something.